# How to perform scp between 2 remote unix boxes using Jsch?

Tags: java, unix, remote-access, scp, jsch

I am writing a Java code using Jsch in which I need to perform scp between 2 remote UNIX boxes.

I tried to execute the scp command in the same way as to execute a normal command from my java code like this :

```
JSch jsch=new JSch();
Session session=jsch.getSession("user", "host", 22);
UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
session.setUserInfo(ui);
session.setPassword("pwd");
session.connect();
Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("scp user@mademo.org:/home/user/demo.csv /home/user/demo.csv");
channel.setInputStream(null);
((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
channel.connect();
//Printing operations
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

Instead of prompting password for user@mademo.org as I expected. I get only errors :

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
exit-status: 1
```

From executing the command on the UNIX box directly, I have found this :

scp asks for password to connect to the remote machine.. however using this code, it is not prompting for any password. So it is trying to perform scp without the password and trying thrice(NumberoOFAttempts flag) and gives the error messages...

I want to know how to make scp atleast prompt to enter something instead of just not taking password ... I have used the default implementation of MyUserInfo class given in jsch examples for my code...

Or

Is there any way to provide the password along with the scp command ?? I am trying to avoid using private/public key combinations as much as possible..

EDIT : 
From Paulo's post.. Now I have added channel.setPty(true) to get a pseudo terminal for the command and it is asking for me to enter Password than failing automatically..

How should I specify the password now... I tried typing it in the console but it is not accepting and keeps on waiting for user input.... I tried setting it using channel.setInputStream(pwdbytes); but it keeps waiting at the command and not taking the input ..

Thanks for any help regarding this...

Comment: `session.setPassword("pwd");` looks wrong, since you're meant to be getting the password from the MyUserInfo class. Does it work without that line?

Comment: It is working with or without the line.. I have set the password here using setPassword... If I removed that, I have to specify the password in the MyUserInfo class... No problems because of that...

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid public/private keys? They are the standard way of doing things.

Comment: Try opening "shell" in channel. Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");

Comment: @artbristol..  I would have some problems in storing the keys in the remote machine.  and it would take some time too... So I m trying to avoid using them..

Comment: @nIKUNJ.. getting Class cast exception ... How is it possible to set command in Shell Channel ?? channel.setCommand() is not present for CommandShell ... Reason for exception...

Answer (score 3):

The `scp` command on your first Unix box tries to read the password from the console/terminal.  But this will only work when there is a terminal associated with the process - and it is not, by default.

The easiest way to solve this would be to use [`channel.setPty(true)`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html#setPty%28boolean%29) before connecting the channel, and then provide the password via the input/output streams.

Comment: @Paulo... Thanks for telling that... I have included it in the code.. Now it is asking for me to enter Password.. How should I specify the password now... I tried typing it in the console but it is not accepting and keeps on waiting for user input.... 
I tried setting it using  channel.setInputStream(pwdbytes); but it keeps waiting at the command and not taking the input .. What should be done ??